# How to use protobuf's SerializeToOstream and ParseFromIstream for IPC via fifo?

Tags: c++, linux, stream, protocol-buffers, fifo

I have client that send messages serialized by protobuf to the server via linux fifo. I use ifstream and ofstream in my code for I / O operations.

If I write like this:

```
//client
Client::request() {
  std::ofstream pipeOut;
  pipeOut.open(outputPipeName);
  msg.SerializeToOstream(&pipeOut);
  pipeOut.close();
  ...
}

//server
Server::process_requests() {
  std::ifstream pipeIn;

  while(isRunning) {
    pipeIn.open(inputPipeName);
    msg.ParseFromIstream(&pipeIn);
    pipeIn.close();
    ...
  }

}
```

everything works perfectly. But I don't want to constantly open and close the streams. Instead, I want to write something like this:

```
//client
class Client {
  std::ofstream pipeOut;
};

Client::Client() {
  pipeOut.open(outputPipeName);
}

Client::~Client() {
  pipeOut.close();
}


Client::request() {
  msg.SerializeToOstream(&pipeOut);
  ...
}

//server
Server::process_requests() {
  std::ifstream pipeIn;
  pipeIn.open(inputPipeName);  

  while(isRunning) {
    msg.ParseFromIstream(&pipeIn);
    ...
  }

  pipeIn.close();
}
```

but with this code server blockes inside ParseFromIstream function and the execution of the program goes no further. Can anybody please tell me how to write this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was that I used the wrong method for serialization and the protobuff didn't know when the message would end and waited for the next part of the message until the pipe was closed. That is why the first version of the code worked, and the second one didn't. I managed to fix this behavior using [Delimiting Protobuf Messages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Delimiting+Protobuf+Messages).

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing pipeOut after "msg.SerializeToOstream(&pipeOut)" via ostream's .flush() function. Closing the stream flushes it so that's why the first code example works. When you keep the stream open and write less than the stream buffer size worth of data to it that data isn't made available to the read side unless/until more data is written to fill the buffer and prompt it to be sent OR a flush operation is done.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought about, but no. I wrote in the answer what was the problem.